# Error: stat_bin requires the following missing aesthetics: x

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a histogram representing the roll of a pair of dice.

```
roll <- function() {
    die=1:6    
    ra<-sample(x=die,size=2,replace=T)
    sum(ra)
}

giz <- replicate(100, roll())

ggplot2::qplot(giz, binwidth=1)
```

But I am getting the error:

> stat_bin requires the following missing aesthetics: x

Comment: This worked for me. With out any issues

Comment: Same, works for me. What version of `ggplot2` is this? Note that I added that to your post since you didn't say where `qplot` fame from